# EventLog appender C# does not write in event log viewer

Tags: c#, event-log, event-viewer

I need to make my C# application to write log in Windows Event viewer.

I Used ,

```
 <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <param name="ApplicationName" value="DataLoader" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value='{"Processed":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}","Loglevel":"%p","Service":"DataLoader","Instance":"","AdditionalInfo":"%c{1}|%M","logtext":"%m%n"}'/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

No Errors in Console but it does not write logs in windows event viewer

Comment: Is that all?Did you define your event sources?

Comment: Yes i have defined event source in registry

Comment: `public class MyEventSource:EventSource{
 void Debug(string formatted, string message, string environment, string member, string path, int line) {
            WriteEvent(6, formatted, message, environment, member, path, line);
        }
}`

something like these

Comment: I used xml config file for Windows event log writing. we found that the application name does not match with registry source

Comment: Changed   <param name="ApplicationName" value="Log4net" />  and it was worked. But Still i have doubt that why DataLoader not able to write event log Since i have created Dataloader source in registry

Comment: I tried with some other source name it is working fine. But when i tried with name "DataLoader" It is not working